# Scan barcode from mobile browser through web application(Without any mobile application)

Tags: javascript, web-applications, barcode, mobile-website, mobile-browser

We have a web application kind of E-Commerce and now we like to add a **barcode scanning** option to show product details.

But as per my analysis , From **mobile browser**, when user click on scan now button , should redirect to Barcode scanning app and agin get back to our website once scan detect barcode.

I like to know , is it possible to achieve this **with out any specific application**, 
So once user click the **Scan Now** button from **mobile browser(Chrome,safari, firefox)** , should access the camera and scanning has to be happen until detect barcode value or user cancel the process.

If it's possible , which library will suits me.

Hope will get solution/suggestion